# mature, powerful Perl library to support text/string operation?

Tags: perl

Do we have a mature, powerful Perl library to support text/string operation ? for example, if I need to trim a string, I need to write a function like below.

Then question is, do we have an existing API so that I can import and call it ? just like StringUtils.trim(s) in Apache Common Lang.

Thanks.

```
sub trim($) {
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read up on Perl's infamous [function prototypes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bperl+%2Bfunction+%2Bprototypes) and why they can be evil.

Comment: A complement to the Tin Man's suggestion: The pseudo-famous Far More than Everything You've Ever Wanted to Know about Prototypes in Perl: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966

Answer (score 3):

Most string operations in StringUtils are so trivially done in Perl that I question the need for such a module.  Yes, it would produce more readable code to those less familiar with Perl, but it would require learning the peculiarities of the given routines, which would be more work for those more familiar with Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [String::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aUtil)?

Searching [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) should be your first step when looking for libraries.

Here are a few other string modules:

- http://search.cpan.org/modlist/String_Language_Text_Processing/String
- http://search.cpan.org/modlist/String_Language_Text_Processing/Text

Comment: +1: I wish that more people would search before asking... is Google that hard to use?

Comment: Empirical data suggests it is. I'm thinking I should add "Knows how to use Google" to my resume because it's such a rare skill. :-)

Comment: I am BrainBench(TM) Certified in Google.

Comment: Google sucks for finding perl things, imo